# Can $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $ L^q(\mathbb{R})$ be isomorphic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $p,q \in (1,\infty)$ with $p\neq q$.  Are the Banach spaces $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $L^q(\mathbb{R})$  isomorphic?

Comment: Re-tagged functional analysis. Expect question to be closed, as completely standard (and looking very much like homework).


Comment: Would it be possible to provide a reference to this completely standard result?  This is not a HW problem. 

Comment: Is it really standard? Of course we know that the two Banach spaces are isomorphic when $p$ and $q$ are conjugate, but if they are not conjugate it's not obvious to me that $L^p$ and $L^q$ will not be isomorphic (but I don't know much in functional analysis, so perhaps it's indeed standard).

Comment: Perhaps I might rephrase the question to make it less localized.  Given two Banach spaces, what methods can one use to prove they are _not_ isomorphic?  A reference would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question for a non expert to ask. Can anyone who voted to close prove that $L_4(0,1)$ is not isomorphic to $L_6(0,1)$? 

In practice, it is quite difficult to decide whether 2 Banach spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: @Guillaume Brunerie: Contrary to what you said, $L_p$ and $L_q$ are NOT isomorphic when $p$ and $q$ are non equal conjugate indices. What is your obvious proof that they are not isomorphic when the indices are not conjugate?  I would like to see such a proof.

Comment: @Bill Johnson: Oh indeed, they are not isomorphic but one is isomorphic to the dual of the other, sorry. I remember that when I saw $L^p$ spaces the first time I did not understand why everybody was saying that $L^p$ is the dual of $L^{p*}$ whereas it could perfectly well be the case that $L^4$ is isomorphic to $L^6$.

Comment: @Bill: Quick Google search for "Lp and Lq are not isomorphic" gives this book http://books.google.com/books?id=Hcqm4_lW4EkC&pg=PA180&dq=Lp+and+Lq+are+not+isomorphic&hl=en&ei=1AywTtroPMfAtgei9J2iAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBQ#v=snippet&q=1.38&f=false, page 180. 

Comment: Sure, Mark, and it is in other books as well (going back to Banach's classic).  You will not find it in basic texts, though, and the result is certainly not obvious.  I have been asked this exact question by famous people who work in a different part of functional analysis. 

Comment: I agree with Bill on this.

Comment: @Bill: the key here is not that it is in a book, but that a 1 minute Google search is enough to answer that question. 

Comment: I started a meta thread about this: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1197/interesting-questions-easily-answered-by-searches/

Comment: @Mark Sapir: currently a quick google search for "Lp and Lq isomorphic" gives the above MO answer as a first result. So you are right, I guess. But Bill too ;)

Answer (score 42):

The proof Fabian alludes to in the book reference Mark gave is a modern one using the notions of cotype and type.  One way to prove that a Banach space $X$ is not isomorphic to a Banach space $Y$ is to exhibit a property that is preserved under isomorphisms that $X$ has but $Y$ does not.  Type and cotype are examples of such properties.  The (best) type and cotype of $L_p$ are calculated in many books.  I suggest you look at Theorem 6.2.14 in the book of Albiac and Kalton.  From the statement you see that if $p\not=q$, then $L_p$ and $L_q$ either have different (best) type or different (best) cotype.

Type and cotype depend only on the collection of finite dimensional subspaces of a space (we call such a property a local property).  So you cannot use either to prove, e.g., that $L_p$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_p$ when $p\not= 2$.  One way of proving this is to show that $\ell_2$ embeds isomorphically into $L_p$ but not into $\ell_p$ when $p\not=2$.  These facts you can also find in Albiac-Kalton. You can also use infinite dimensional techniques to prove that $L_p$ and $L_q$ are not isomorphic when $p\not=q$.  Banach knew this result through infinite dimensional considerations--the concepts of type and cotype came on the scene only 40 years ago.

You will also find in Albiac-Kalton a discussion of when $L_p$ or $\ell_p$ embeds isomorphically into $L_q$. That is more complicated and in fact Banach did not know everything. He called the question the problem of the linear dimension of $L_p$ spaces, IIRC.

Comment: @Bill: Out of curiosity, what was Banach's original argument for proving $L_p$ is not isomorphic to $L_q$?

Comment: Look at Chapter XII in Banach's book, Yemon, where he discusses the linear dimension of the `$L_p$` and `$\ell_p$` spaces.  He shows that they are of incomparable linear dimension except possibly that   `$\ell_q`$ or `$L_q$` embeds into `$L_p$` when $p<q<2$ or $2<q<p$ `$^1$`.  Of course, we now know that $\ell_q$ and $L_q$ do not embed into `$L_p$` when $2<q<p$ but do embed even isometrically when $p<q<2$. If you have Oeuvres vol. II version, there is a nice update   to Banach's book written in 1979 by Pelczynski.  

1. Well, except that `$L_2$` isometrically embeds into all `$L_p$` spaces.

Comment: How do you make a line break in a comment?

Comment: From linear dimension results in Banach's book, you can check the non isomorphism results even though the linear dimension problem was not completely solved until much later. 

BTW: When Banach says that the linear dimension of $X$ is less than the linear dimension of $Y$, he means that $X$ embeds isomorphically into $Y$.

Comment: Completely tangential: software doesn't like line breaks in comments. You can cheat, however, by using an empty math environment. $$ $$ Like this. (Credit goes to Will Jagy for showing me it.)

Comment: @BillJohnson Does type/co-type argument give anything about embeddability of finite-dimensional subspaces? For instance, when $p>2$ and $p\neq q$, I want to show that any finite-dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ cannot be embedded with a constant distortion into $\ell_q$. The case of $p>q$ would follow from a co-type argument. Is there a quick argument for the case of $p<q$?

Comment: The hard case is $2<p<q<\infty$, where the spaces have the same type and $\ell_p$ has better cotype than $\ell_q$. You can use Kadec-Pelczynski after taking ultra products.  "All" you need to know is that ultra products of $L_p$ spaces is again an abstract $L_p$ space, and then that an abstract $L_p$ space is isometrically isomorphic to $L_p(\mu)$ for some measure $\mu$. Or you can localize Kadec-Pelczynski--this was done by Pelczynski and Rosenthal in a paper titled "Localization Techniques in $L^p$ spaces".