# Fourier transform surjective on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $p \in (1,2)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know that $F_2:L^2 \rightarrow L^2$ is of course unitary, whereas $F_1:L^1 \rightarrow C_0$ is injective but not surjective. This can be seen by looking at the dual map.

Riesz-Thorin gives us that there is also $F_p: L^p \rightarrow L^q$ for $p \in (1,2).$ Here, the dual map trick does not work, so this transform has a chance of being surjective. Since every $f \in L^q$ is also in $S'$ we can also define a promising candidate $F_{S'}^{-1}(f).$ Unfortunatly, this does not really tell me whether this $F_{S'}^{-1}(f) \in L^p$ again.

This raises the question whether $F_p$ is actually surjective or not?

Comment on the discussion below: Thanks to everybody participating in the disccusion. Actually this question came to my mind while I was thinking about [this problem from PDEs, which would have an easy solution in this case.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238697/solution-to-inhomogenous-pde) I have to admit that the fact that $L^p$ is not isomorphic to $L^q$ is indeed something I know, but I have never actually used it, as I am not primarily active in analysis. Probably I should give my questions more thought in the future.Sorry for any inconvenience my question caused.

Comment: Leopold, could you define $S'$? I'm at least not familiar with the notation.

Comment: space of tempered distributions

Comment: $F_p$ is injective, and $L_p$ is not isomorphic to $L_q$ unless $p=q=2$, so the answer is no.

Comment: I think it is better to add it in the Original post.

Comment: @YemonChoi , is there a bigger space $X$ on which you can define a Fourier Transform so that $F(X) = L^p$?

Comment: @AmirSagiv It would depend what you wanted your "space" to be -- a space of functions? a space of distributions? I could just define X to be the completion of Schwartz space with respect to the norm $\Vert u\Vert := \Vert F(u) \Vert_p$

Comment: The fact cited by @YemonChoi, that $L_p$ and $L_q$ are not isomorphic, is true but not obvious: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79713/lp-mathbbr-vs-lq-mathbbr for more details.  But I think this should be posted as an answer!

Comment: The Fourier transform is not surjective on $L^p$ for any $p>2$ because there are $L^p$ functions whose FT (in $\mathcal S'$) is not even a function. This is "well known," as the phrase goes, so some googling should give you more information.

Comment: More explicitly, there are purely singular measures whose FT is in $L^p$ for a given $p>2$ (and you can even get pointwise decay with a power rate). These can be constructed using Riesz products, for example.

Comment: @NateEldredge: In Yemon's argument, we don't really need the full force of the theorem that $L^p, L^q$ are not isomorphic. In our situation, the FT itself would be a continuous map $L^p\to L^q$, $p>2$ (by the closed graph theorem), and I think it's pretty easy to show that this isn't true.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree with "true but not obvious" and thought there should be a better answer along the lines given by Christian Remling -- whose comments would make a better answer than mine, I think!

Comment: @YemonChoi: See also my latest comment please regarding your argument. (The question itself is hardly research level, no matter how one looks at it.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Are we all on the same page?  It looks to me like the OP is considering the Fourier transform as a map from $L^p$ to $L^q$ where $1 < p < 2$ (not $p>2$) and $1/p + 1/q = 1$.  This is a well-defined continuous map by the Hausdorff-Young inequality.  Oh, are you saying that if it were surjective, then by Fourier inversion, the Fourier transform would also be continuous from $L^q$ back to $L^p$? Which it isn't.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Well, MO is for people to get answers to things which are easy to those with the right knowledge but not so obvious to people _in a different area_, right? I mean, all my questions about finite group theory and group characters are the kinds of thing that algebraists might learn in "graduate education" but which I simply didn't

Comment: I agree that this seems research level and appropriate for this site, even though it might be easy for specialists.  I sort of work in functional analysis and it wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, you should never miss an opportunity to use the word '[penultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penultimate)'.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $1\leq p<2$ then $\mathscr{F}: L^p \to L^{p'}$  is not surjective.  I had this as a homework problem a week back.

The reason is the bounded inverse theorem:  $\mathscr{F}: L^p \to L^{p'}$ is injective, (by fourier inversion on the dense subspace of schwarz functions).  If the map were surjective then there would be an inverse that would be continuous, since $\mathscr{F}$ is an open map under this assumption.

Thus we just need to prove that there is no bounded inverse:  For $f \in \mathscr{S}$, there is no constant $c$ such that $ ||f||_{p} \leq c ||\hat f||_{p'}$ for $f \in \mathscr{S}$ with the constant only depending on $p$.

This is easy:  The function $f_\lambda=e^{-\pi i \lambda x^2-\pi x^2}$ satisfies $||f_\lambda||_p=c$ independent of $\lambda$, whereas $||\hat f_\lambda||_{p'} \leq c \lambda^{1/p'-1/2}$.  But there is no constant such that $c \leq \lambda^{1/p'-1/2} $ for all $\lambda >0$.  Therefore the fourier transform is not surjective from $L^p \to L^{p'}$ for $1\leq p<2$