# The largest topological copy of a Hilbert space contained in $\ell^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let us consider  $\ell^1$, the space of absolutely  summable sequences in the space of complex numbers. Clearly every finite dimensional Hilbert space is topologically embedded into $\ell^1$.

Convention.  For given Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$, let us write $H\leq K$ if the Hilbertian dimension of $H$ is less than $K$.

Q. What is the Hilbertian dimension of the largest Hilbert space which can be topologically embedded into $\ell^1$?

Comment: Your convention is not used in the question, so why include it?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79713/can-lp-mathbbr-and-lq-mathbbr-be-isomorphic/79892#79892

Comment: ANSWER: $\ l^2\ $ is TOPOLOGICALLY embeddable in $\ l^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No infinite dimensional reflexive space can be embedded into $\ell_1$, because every infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\ell_1$ has a non separable dual.

Comment: Since the question is just about a topological embedding, is it obvious that the image is closed?

Comment: @Pietro Majer What happens if  we change the roles? I mean what is the Hilbertian dimension  of the smallest Hilbert space  contains $\ell^1$ up to topological vector spaces.

Comment: @Spice yes because it is complete

Comment: @GABB In this case, note that any closed subspace is Hilbert, so we can't find $\ell_1$

Comment: rmk: Of course if one only wants a homeo onto a subspace, not necessarily linear, then $\ell_2$ is already homeomorphic to $\ell_1$, via $\ell_2\ni x:=(x_j)_j\mapsto (|x_j|x_j)_j\in\ell_1$

Comment: @Pietro Majer: I feel these two questions will be complicated when the embedding is considered up to topological spaces.     I mean the linear assumption  removes.

Comment: @PietroMajer, sorry, what I meant is:  is it obvious that a mere *topological* embedding will preserve completeness?  (Maybe the fact that the uniform, if not the metric, structure is preserved is good enough here.)

Comment: @LSpice of course  topological embedding (not necessarily linear) need not preserve completeness- e.g. R can be embedded in R as an open interval. But   the question is only meaningful in the top. linear sense ($\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are already homeomorphic, as topological spaces)